# Selenium dropmenu is div

Tags: python, selenium, element

i am using python+selenium simulate click option from drop menu

here is the drop menu picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng9vj.png)

and here is the pagesource of 3 different options

```
<a onclick="DigitSelected('TabMasterContent','N','sub_3','3587822','C')"><table class="chRT"><tbody><tr><td class="chC1p">C</td><td class="chC2p">Hastelloy C-22</td><td class="chC3p">526.00</td><td class="chC4p">73.64</td><td class="chC5p">0</td></tr></tbody></table></a>
<a onclick="DigitSelected('TabMasterContent','N','sub_3','3587823','D')"><table class="chRT"><tbody><tr><td class="chSC1p">D</td><td class="chSC2p">Hastelloy C-4 (2.4610)</td><td class="chSC3p">0.00</td><td class="chSC4p">0.00</td><td class="chSC5p">0</td></tr></tbody></table></a>
<a onclick="DigitSelected('TabMasterContent','N','sub_3','3587824','S')"><table class="chRT"><tbody><tr><td class="chC1p">S</td><td class="chC2p">Stainless steel 316</td><td class="chC3p">0.00</td><td class="chC4p">0.00</td><td class="chC5p">0</td></tr></tbody></table></a>
```

what I want to do is simply simulate click different options. i am using selenium IDE got the code should be like this

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".chRow:nth-child(2) .chC2p").click()
```

but i just simply want to use code select different options from the first letter of the options , "C", "D","S" , do you have any good ideas to do that?
such as this one , I know it is not work

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("S").click
```

Comment: You could use XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `XPath`.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[.//td[text()='C']]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[.//td[text()='D']]"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[.//td[text()='S']]"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have shared all the child `<td>` tags seems to be with in individual `<a>` tags. Now as the elements are [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled elements to `click()` on different options you you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following **xpath** [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Clicking on the row with **Digit** as **`C`**:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@onclick,'DigitSelected')][./table/tbody/tr/td[text()='C']]")))
  ```
- Clicking on the row with **Digit** as **`D`**:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@onclick,'DigitSelected')][./table/tbody/tr/td[text()='D']]")))
  ```
- Clicking on the row with **Digit** as **`S`**:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@onclick,'DigitSelected')][./table/tbody/tr/td[text()='S']]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```